# Splitting a string in two after a specific character is seen in python

Tags: python, string, split, calculation

I am trying to create a grade calculator that performs an operation based on what is inputted before and after the operator instead of asking for two separate inputs. For example:

```
input = input("Grade: ")
```

input would be something like "19/25" and the program would divide 19/25

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inp = input("Insert operation: ")
print(f"Result: {eval(inp)}")
```